# how or in what procedure a C program calculation runs when any sum of 2 numbers exceeds the maximum value?

Tags: c, int, overflow

example for int in c when I add (2^31 - 1) + 1 it gives the output -2^31..again -2^31 + 1 gives the output -(2^31 + 1)..In what procedure computer makes such operation?

Comment: ... What? I can't tell what your question is.

Comment: according to [Number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_line) it wraps.

Answer (score 1):

In C, when the sum of 2 `int` exceed the range of `int`, the result is undefined behavior.  Code should not rely on a specific result.  No particular procedure runs in such a case - the results are undefined.

When the mathematical sum of 2 `unsigned` exceeds the range of `unsigned`, the mathematical `UINT_MAX + 1` is subtracted to bring the result in range.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is inherent in how the computer represents the numbers.  It's a system called [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  It isn't something you should rely on, though, because it won't be portable.  If another computer system uses a different mechanism for representing the numbers, who knows what result you'd get!